# C# Selenium 3.8 + Firefox 57 run as windows service

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I have a Windows service that is successfully running on Firefox 46 + Selenium 2.53. I am in the process of updating the versions to Firefox 57 + Selenium 3.8. On localhost debug standalone is working but when I run it as a Windows service I get this error:

> Process unexpectedly closed with status: 0

My code is

```
try
{
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.SetPreference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled", false);
    profile.SetPreference("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Services\\RoboLEDBBService\\geckodriver.exe");

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.Profile = profile;
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
}
catch (Exception error)
{ }
```

Comment: I'm having this exact problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can set this:

```
options.SetPreference("security.sandbox.content.level", 5);
```